# How does "location = url" submit a form in OpenCart?

Tags: jquery, forms, opencart2.x

I have a filter form in OpenCart which shows the list of order.

It is submitting the form using the onclick event of a button. I noticed the function which is as follows...

```
$('#button-filter').on('click', function() {
  url = 'index.php?route=sale/order&token=<?php echo $token; ?>';

  var filter_order_id = $('input[name=\'filter_order_id\']').val();
  if (filter_order_id) {
     url += '&filter_order_id=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_order_id);
  }

  var filter_customer = $('input[name=\'filter_customer\']').val();
  if (filter_customer) {
     url += '&filter_customer=' + encodeURIComponent(filter_customer);
  }
  location = url;
});
```

How does "location = url" submit the form? Is there any configuration done in OpenCart for this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: I got it @RahulChandrasekharan. Thanks.